# Angular 9 : How to change navbar from child component?

Tags: html, css, angular9

I want to be able to change the navbar depending on the component. My goal is to change background IMG and background height.

To do this I create a service with behaviorSubject that looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DimensionService {




  private dimension = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  broadCast = this.dimension.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  updateDimension(dimension: any) {
    this.dimension.next(dimension);
  }
}
```

Since navbar is in app.component, I set default value in oninit like this:

```
dimension: any = { height: 400, img: '/assets/img/default.img' }

        ngOnInit(): void {


            this.dimensionService
                .subscribe(dim =>{this.dimension = dim});
    }
```

in child component I update main component like this:

```
dimension: any = { height: 400, img: '/assets/img/default.img' }

            ngOnInit(): void {


                this.dimensionService
                    updateDimension({height: 300, img: '/assets/img/child.png'});
        }
```

I want every component to have is own navbar height and background img.

In app.component.html I have this :

```html
<div [style.height.px]="dimension.height" [ngStyle]="{backgroundImage:'url(' + dimension.img + ')'}" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; background-size: cover; position: relative;">
...
....
</div>
```

I implementation don't seem to be correct. I am having this error:

[image]

Can anyone help to handle this kind of situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are changing the value of the `BehaviourSubject` 3 times at the same time. When your application renders, `angular` checks & preserves your value in its storage container to prevent variable leak (global access). So, when you created the `BehaviourSubject` it emitted on value which is `null`. While the `angular` is preserving this value, instantaneously, another value got emitted. That's why the error. The sol. is to remove the default configuration from the navbar & use the them as default value in the `BehaviourSubject`.

For a fix in your case:

`dimension.service.ts`

```
private dimension = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
  height: 400,
  img: '/assets/img/default.img'
});
```

`navbar.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dimesionService.subscribe(dim => {
    this.dimension = dim
  });
}
```

`child.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dimesionService.updateDimension({
    height: 300,
    img: '/assets/img/child.png'
  });
}
```